# How to create Dynamic Control in Dynamic form Module in DNN?

Tags: dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

Actually I have a DropDownList, Which have values 1,2,3,4,5,6.And Under this some controls 2 RadioButtons,3 CheckBox Group and 4 TextBoxes. When i select value 1 from DropDown These controls display once,when i select value 2 from dropDown , these controls display twice and so on. So how can i do this? Please help anyone . Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that with jquery, somthing like this:

```
jQuery('<div/>').appentTo('#body')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this in two (or more) way:

- add 6 "multiview" controls each of it has an empty view in it and filled view with the desired controls.
  If you switch your dropdownlist you can call:

  ```
  mvMymultiView1.SetActiveView(vShowControls);
  mvMymultiView1.SetActiveView(vEmptyView);`
  ```
- you can place 6 Controls of `<asp:placeholder>` on your page and fill them dynamically with new Controls at runtime.

I would prefer my first way to achive your target. This is pretty easy cause you can show or hide your controls rly easy and fast without deleting or creating any control at runtime.